# Boolean Required Here

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, boolean

The following logic gives me a Boolean Required Here error. Where am I going wrong?

```
{RV_Practitioner.IgnoreCertificationException} and
if ({RV_Practitioner_ID_Numbers.DocumentName} = ["NPI Number"])
then {RV_Practitioner_ID_Numbers.DocumentName} in ["NPI Number"]
else "No NPI"
```

Comment: Where are you using this logic, and what are you trying to make it do?

Comment: What I am really trying to do is limit the Document name to "NPI number" and show a string of "No NPI". I am still getting the boolean error with:                                                                                                 If ({RV_Practitioner_ID_Numbers.DocumentName} = "NPI Number") Then
 {RV_Practitioner_ID_Numbers.DocumentName} in ["NPI Number"]
Else
    "No NPI"

Comment: Most importantly: *Where* are you using this logic? In a formula? In a suppression field? Where is it being used?

Comment: In a select expert formula

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that new information.

Comment: does it work if you comment out your `and/if/then/else`?  I'm wondering if you need a 'formula=' (vb syntax) prefix

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the string "No NPI" when the system is looking for a Boolean. For example, the Record Selection formula evaluates each record to determine whether or not to include each record in the report. Valid answers for that are True or False, and "No NPI" is not valid.

Remove that entire Else clause and instead write a separate formula to display "No NPI" when there are no NPIs to display. (Hint: when there are a total of zero)

Comment: What I am really trying to do is limit the Document name to "NPI number" and show a string of "No NPI" if the record does not contain a NPI Number document name. I removed the And statement for the IgnorCertException and am still getting the same boolean error with this:                                                                                                                             If ({RV_Practitioner_ID_Numbers.DocumentName} = "NPI Number") Then
 {RV_Practitioner_ID_Numbers.DocumentName} in ["NPI Number"]
Else
    "No NPI"